# cdc ON secondary database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, cdc

I have a cluster of databases, one primary and two secondary. I need to enable CDC on a database, but I want to enable it on one of the secondary databases to eliminate any resource consumption on the primary database (similar to SQL Server secondary database backup). Is this possible to do it and how? If not: can you tell me the best practices for enabling CDC on cluster?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to enable it on one of the secondary databases to eliminate any resource consumption on the primary database

This is not possible.  CDC writes the changes back to system tables in the target database, so must run against the primary replica.  See [Replication, change tracking, & change data capture - Always On availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/replicate-track-change-data-capture-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-2017#CDC)